# Send Commit message on Acquia Hook by Slack

Tags: acquia-cloud

Based on [Automating with Cloud Hooks](https://docs.acquia.com/acquia-cloud/develop/api/cloud-hooks/) I've implemented  Slack notification based on [Simple Slack Notification Bash Script](https://github.com/acquia/cloud-hooks/blob/master/samples/slack/README.md)

```
site="$1"
target_env="$2"
source_branch="$3"
deployed_tag="$4"
repo_url="$5"
repo_type="$6"

FILE=$HOME/slack_settings

if [ -f $FILE ]; then
  # Load the Slack webhook URL (which is not stored in this repo).
  . $HOME/slack_settings

  # Post deployment notice to Slack

  if [ "$source_branch" != "$deployed_tag" ]; then
    curl -X POST --data-urlencode "payload={\"username\": \"Acquia Cloud\", \"text\": \"An updated deployment has been made to *$site.$target_env* using branch *$source_branch* as *$deployed_tag*.\", \"icon_emoji\": \":acquiacloud:\"}" $SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL
  else
    curl -X POST --data-urlencode "payload={\"username\": \"Acquia Cloud\", \"text\": \"An updated deployment has been made to *$site.$target_env* using tag *$deployed_tag*.\", \"icon_emoji\": \":acquiacloud:\"}" $SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL
  fi
else
  echo "File $FILE does not exist."
fi
```

It works correctly, it sends the message,

> An updated deployment has been made to *mysitexxxx.dev* using tag *dev*.

**But What I need is the commit's message,How can I get commit message on Acquia post-code-update?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commit message isn't passed in to the script, so you have to get it from somewhere else. I'm not sure if there is a git repository available to the cloud hook scripts on Acquia's cloud servers in general (it seems like there must be, but...I can't find an answer about where it is in their docs). You do have the repository url and the branch/tag, so you could try a shallow clone of the tag to get the data:

`` git clone --depth 1 --branch $deployed_tag $repo_url clonedirectory
cd clonedirectory
commit_message=`git show -s --format=%B`
...
echo $commit_message ``

You can use the `$commit_message` variable in the slack commands.

Of course...you have to figure out how to authenticate to the git repo and I'm not sure what's a great solution there.

Really I hope someone will reply with the location of a git clone that's available on cloud servers.

Comment: good tricky solution: I just use commit_message=`git log -1` instead of  commit_message=`git show -s --format=%B`

Answer (score 0):

Old question but still relevant.  Here is a way to implement greggles solution with better performance. It will use the same shallow clone rather than creating one each push / deploy.

ssh into your Acquia server.

Make a git directory under the home directory

cd into it and do the shallow clone into it, e.g.

`git clone --depth 1 --no-single-branch $repo_url $site`

Use your Acquia git URL for the $repo_url and the site name for the directory (e.g the application short name).

This will be the git clone used for your commit info in the hook.

In the hook script, you can now do something like:

```
cwd=`pwd`
cd $HOME/git/$site
git checkout $source_branch
git pull
commit=`git log -1 --pretty=format:"%h %an%x09%ad%x09%s" --date=format:"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"`
cd $cwd
```

Add the commit variable to your slack message text.

Notes:

To add a newline in the message use: `\\n` in the string.

Also, the shallow repo may not have all the log info in it, but since we only want the last one that is OK.

If you are worried about disk usage, you should remove and reclone the git repo to cut back its size.  Each pull will increase disk usage.